# How to get mails correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I am new to Rails and I am faced with a problem:
I have to build an app for a Coworking Area. Freelancers complete a form and they can have one of these two statuses: accept or confirm.
I handle this with Enum type.
I can get their mails: Freelancer.confirm.map{ |freelancer| freelancer.email }

In Rails console:

> Freelancer Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "freelancers".* FROM "freelancers"
>   WHERE "freelancers"."status" = ?  [["status", 0]]  =>
>   ["freelancer1@mail.com", "freelancer2@mail.com",
>   "freelancer3@mail.fr", "freelancer4@mail.com", "freelancer5@mail.fr",
>   "freelancer6@mail.com", "freelancer7@mail.com",
>   "freelancer8@mail.com", "freelancer9@mail.com",
>   "freelancer10@mail.com", "freelancer11@mail.com"]

But I can't use it correctly in my app:

In my app/models/freelancer.rb

```
class Freelancer < ApplicationRecord
    enum status: [:confirm, :accept]

    def send_contract_email
        UserMailer.contract_email(self).deliver_now
    end
end
```

In app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def contract_email(freelancers)
        @emails = freelancers.accept.map{|freelancer| freelancer.email}
        mail(to: @emails, subject: 'Welcome to my site')
    end
end
```

In lib/tasks/email_tasks.rake

```
desc 'send contract email'
task send_contract_email: :environment do
    UserMailer.contract_email(freelancers).deliver_now
end
```

In config/environments/schedule.rb (set to 5 minutes for more convenience)

```
every '5 * * * *' do
    rake 'send_contract_email'
end
```

And in app/views/user_mailer/contract_email.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hi!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run 
rake send_contract_email 
for testing everything works and checking whether the email is sent or not, it displays an error:

> rake aborted! NameError: undefined local variable or method
>   `freelancers' for main:Object
>   /home/gaelle/Bureau/corworking/coworking/lib/tasks/email_tasks.rake:3:in`
>   block in '
>   /home/gaelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /home/gaelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`
>   eval'
>   /home/gaelle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
>   `' Tasks: TOP => send_contract_email (See full trace by running
>   task with --trace)

The problem seems to be in UserMailer but I can not understand why I am wrong because I use Freelancer (with self) in the model.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Its pretty obvious - you're using the variable `freelancers` without defining it in your rake task. `UserMailer.contract_email(Freelancer.all).deliver_now`

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot too !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in your task, `send_contract_email`, you're using a local variable `freelancers` that hasn't been initialized. You'll need to set `freelancers` to be a list of freelancers in the task before calling `UserMailer.contract_email`, or else pass the list into the task as a parameter. [Here's a nice post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-use-arguments-in-a-rake-task) with information about how to pass parameters to rake tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and link. I save it for next time.